# Windows batch to loop through values for variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have main set of values and a subset to it

Main Set: `Group1,Group2,Group3`

Subset : `Group1_Sub1,Group1_Sub2,Group2_Sub1,Group3_Sub1,Group3_Sub2`

```
Group1 ->Group1_Sub1 and Group1_Sub2

Group2 ->Group2_Sub1

Group3 ->Group3_Sub1,Group3_Sub2
```

For each main list, I would like to loop only through its corresponding sub group list and display output.

Currently I am using below code

```
for %%s in (

Group1,Group2,Group3

    ) do (

        echo set Main Group %%s >> Log.txt

        for %%i in (
                    Group1_Sub1,Group1_Sub2,Group2_Sub1,Group3_Sub1,Group3_Sub2
                    ) do (
                        echo Main Group is %%s and its sub group is %%i >>Log.txt
                         )
            )
```

Above code will give me the out put as :

```
set Main Group Group1 
Main Grpup is Group1 and its sub group is Group1_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group1 and its sub group is Group1_Sub2 
Main Grpup is Group1 and its sub group is Group2_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group1 and its sub group is Group3_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group1 and its sub group is Group3_Sub2 
set Main Group Group2 
Main Grpup is Group2 and its sub group is Group1_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group2 and its sub group is Group1_Sub2 
Main Grpup is Group2 and its sub group is Group2_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group2 and its sub group is Group3_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group2 and its sub group is Group3_Sub2 
set Main Group Group3 
Main Grpup is Group3 and its sub group is Group1_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group3 and its sub group is Group1_Sub2 
Main Grpup is Group3 and its sub group is Group2_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group3 and its sub group is Group3_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group3 and its sub group is Group3_Sub2
```

I would like to restrict them to go through only  its corresponding list like below

```
set Main Group Group1 
Main Grpup is Group1 and its sub group is Group1_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group1 and its sub group is Group1_Sub2 
set Main Group Group2 
Main Grpup is Group2 and its sub group is Group2_Sub1 
set Main Group Group3  
Main Grpup is Group3 and its sub group is Group3_Sub1 
Main Grpup is Group3 and its sub group is Group3_Sub2
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: IIUR parse the output of a set with varying length variable names with a `for /f`, set will output ***all*** vars with a given prefix and their content.

Comment: are you aware that your code doesn't access any variables but just generates the output by concatenating strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within the inner (%%i) loop:

```
    ECHO %%i|FINDSTR /b /i /L /c:"%%s_">nul
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Main Group is %%s and its sub group is %%i >>Log.txt
```

which echoes (eg) `Group1_Sub2` into `findstr` which looks for a string `/b` beginning with the current value of `%%s` + an underscore. `/i` means case-insensitive, `/L` means literal comparison and `/c:` indicates the string to detect.

If `findstr` finds the string it's looking for, then `errorlevel` will be set to 0 or 1 otherwise. The `>nul` suppresses output. `errorlevel` may then be tested using the conventional syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As you speak about variables: the following code looks for the main groups and their sub groups by itself:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM following line just for generating test variables:
for %%a in (1 2 3) do for %%b in (1 2 3 4) do set "Group%%a_Sub%%b=!random!"

REM search MainGroups:
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ('set group') do set "Main_%%a=Group"
REM process each MainGroup
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_=" %%a in ('set Main_') do (
  echo set Main Group %%a
  for /f "delims==" %%b in ('set %%a_') do (
    echo Main Group is %%a and its sub group is %%b and its content is !%%b!
  )
)
```

Pro: no need to hardcode each and every variable name
Con (?): does not list empty (non-existing) variables (depending on your needs, this could even be another Pro)